# AngularJS Bootstrap CSS entry for Cursor Hand Grab

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, cursor

How can I get the cursor to always be a hand / grab for sortable containers using AngularJS & Bootstrap?

What would be the corresponding HTML change to the div tag?

```
        <div ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="responses" class="container-fluid connected-drop-target-sortable" style="height: 100vh;">
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could create a CSS rule that targets any `div`s with the attribute `ui-sortable`:

```
div[ui-sortable] {
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

Here's the [list of cursors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) you can use.